# JavaScript change DIV background using ID

Tags: javascript, background

I have a `<div>` it's ID = "123456"

If I run the following I get 123456 shown in the console.log

```
dId = obj.id,
console.log(dId);
```

If I do this I can change the background

```
document.getElementById("123456").style.background="#EEE000";
```

Yet this fails with "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null**"

```
document.getElementById(dId).style.background="#EEE000";
```

How can I do this using the var **dId** ?

**UPDATE**
For clarity **obj** =

```
<div id="123456" class="drag" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">TEST</div>
```

**obj.id** = 123456

**UPDATE**
New working JFiddle [jsfiddle.net/pyefk58z/2](http://jsfiddle.net/pyefk58z/2/) When an Item is dragged to the drop zone, how do I change that items background color to show it's in the drop list ?

Thanks

Comment: You're not quite giving the full context of the situation. `getElementById(myVariableName)` does indeed work, so it's wrong to assume simply using that structure is what would cause the issue. (Also standard complaint: If you're adding numbers to your IDs, you're using them wrong, etc etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `dId` without `document.getElementById()`.

Also, your ID name is invalid CSS grammar: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/foLxrqrc/

```js
var dId = document.querySelector('#a123456');
console.log(dId);
//document.getElementById("a123456").style.background = "#EEE000";
dId.style.background = "#EEE000";
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a123456"></div>
```

Given what you want `obj` to equal, this will work:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/ewct9kL3/

```js
var obj = document.querySelector('#a123456');
var dId = obj.id;
console.log(dId);
//document.getElementById("a123456").style.background = "#EEE000";
document.getElementById(dId).style.background = "#EEE000";
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a123456" class="drag" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">TEST</div>
```

I still recommend using my first way, but to each his own.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I've updated my original post showing what obj contains and how I get obj.id

Comment: @MacMan, what *doesn't* work? Did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for this. Why when I change `var obj = document.querySelector('#a123456');
var dId = obj.id;` to `var dId = "a123456"`; does it fail ?

Comment: @MacMan, would you put your example in a fiddle and let me know what is failing? I don't see an issue with the code you just posted ...

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure how to make a jfiddle out of this. I'm using this script `http://www.redips.net/my/preview/REDIPS_drag/example23/` and it's an iem that I want to change the background of when it is added to the drop list.

Comment: New working JFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pyefk58z/2/ When an Item is dragged to the drop zone, how do I change that items background color to show it's in the drop list ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dID` as `id`, you should check that `dId` contains the right `id`

```js
var obj = {
  id: 123456 // does not matter string or integer
};

var dId = obj.id;

document.getElementById(dId).style.background = "#EEE000";
```

```html
<div id="123456">
  Test
</div>
```